# Create Action,Story and Type in opengraph in facebook using code from website

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-opengraph

I need to post story on usertimeline via my website.Right now I've created one sample application for that,created story,action and object from app dashboard in facebook and it works, but I don't want to create story from appdashboard each and everytime.I want to create story dynamically from my website.Is it possible to create Open graph API Action and Story from my website?

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible. You must create the stories through the application settings. It wouldn't make sense to programmatically do it since you need to submit for approval anyway.

Comment: Actually I want to create story using data from database.Anyway,thanks.